# The equation $|A^{-1}A|=|A|^2-|A|+1$ for finite subsets of a group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, computational-algebra

Let $A$ be a finite subset of a group $G$. It is clear that $|A^{-1}A|\leq|A|^2-|A|+1$. If $A$ is singleton or $A=\{1,a\}$ with $O(a)\neq 2$ then the equality holds. Now, can somebody characterize all $A$  with the property in some important groups (finite or infinite)? 
$$|A^{-1}A|=|A|^2-|A|+1$$

Comment: A should not be a subgrou except identity.

Answer (score 2):

Such sets are called Golomb rulers, or equivalently Sidon sets. At least when $G$ is abelian, they have been extensively studied. I doubt there is a simpler characterization than your definition.

Comment: interesting. Do you have a reference where to find more on these rulers and sets? How are they used? Combinatorics, graphs?